# Python - dictionaries comparision

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, comparison

I have a problem in python with dictionary comparison. I have 2 dictionaries and I want to compare these and when the key is the same, the value is upgraded to `valueFromFirstDictionary + valueFromSecondDictionary`.

Function 'addToInventory()' should have 45 coins instead of 3, but where is the problem? In the loop, it prints 45, but when I print all the dictionaries it shows 3.

Here's the problem with function:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    dictionaryHelp = {}

    for i in addedItems:                                 
        dictionaryHelp.setdefault(i,0)
        dictionaryHelp[i] = dictionaryHelp[i] + 1

    for i, k in inventory.copy().items():
        for j, l in dictionaryHelp.items():
            #print(i, k, j, l)
            if i == j:
                suma = k + l
                inventory.update({i:suma})
                #inventory[i] = suma
                print(inventory[i])
                break
            else:
                inventory[j] = l

    print(inventory)
    return(inventory)

inv = {'golden coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['golden coin', 'dagger','golden coin', 'golden coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)

for k, v in inv.items():
    print(str(k) + ': ' + str(v))
    item_total = item_total + v
```

The code is also [available on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zeD3Zdmt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `for` loop, take a close look at the `else` stuite, where you use `j`:

```
for i, k in inventory.copy().items():
    for j, l in dictionaryHelp.items():
        if i == j:
            # ...
        else:
            inventory[j] = l
```

You loop over the keys for `inventory()`, and for *each key* you loop over `dictionaryHelp.items()`. And each time `i == j` is **not** true, you set `inventory[j] = l`. It doesn't matter that you set `'golden coin'` to 45 at *some point*, you simply replaced that result.

However, you **don't need to use a double loop**. Dictionaries are *great* at testing if a given key is already there, just use `key in dictionary`; that's true if you can get a value for that key from that dictionary.

That means you don't need to loop over both dictionaries, just use the key from one to see if there is a number for the item in the other:

```
for item, count in dictionaryHelp.items():
    if item in inventory:
        inventory[item] = inventory[item] + count
    else:
        inventory[item] = count
```

- There is no need to copy `inventory` anymore, because you are not looping over it now.
- Instead of testing for `item in inventory`, you could use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to use a default `0` value instead:

  ```
  for item, count in dictionaryHelp.items():
      inventory[item] = inventory.get(item, 0) + count
  ```

  `dict.get()` is similar to using `dict.setdefault()`, but without setting the key in the dictionary to the default value.
- You don't really need to create `dictionaryHelp` either. Just add the counts *directly* to your `inventory` dictionary. I'm using the same `dict.get()` trick here to start with `0` if an added item wasn't yet there in the inventory:

  ```
  def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
      for item in addedItems:
          inventory[item] = inventory.get(item, 0) + 1
      return inventory
  ```